# Running PHP Scripts in R

Tags: php, r, command-line-interface

There's a PHP library that I'm really interested in using.  However, there's no R implementation of it nor do I see an interpreter between the two.  I've searched on Google but it seems like most implementations are either displaying R plots or figures on a webpage via PHP or passing command-line arguments to each script.  R blogger article about PHP and R seemed to be geared towards building a web application.

I've seen `reticulate` package achieve similar this within Python, but I was hoping we have something like this for PHP.

I've thought of a method of passing it through via `exec(paste0('php ', <script>)`, but I don't think that's the best direction to take.

Are there better ways to implement this?

Comment: (1) When I'm looking for something R-related, I often start by googling `cran something`, hoping it'll be mentioned somewhere on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/); in this case, I found a 9-year-old reference to integrating PHP and R, and I think it is not what you want. So I believe nothing formal or well-established exists (I might be wrong). (2) As such, I think you might be stuck with using `system`, `system2`, or even better the `processx` package. (3) Asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library*" is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good luck!

Comment: Ahh my bad @r2evans!  Yeah that's the first step I took and I couldn't find anything formalized or specifically in the direction I was looking for.  I did come across that, but seeing that it wasn't the direction I was looking for, I started looking at R-Bloggers.  Thanks for that recommendation though, I think I'll start having to build it out myself.